# How to Read a Whole Structure Array from Binary File

Tags: arrays, structure

can you please help me with this code.
My Problem is that I can't read the whole Structure From Binary File.(I am Done with Writing Part btw)
I created a Structure in C

```
struct inventory
{
    char c_name[30];
    char model[30];
    char color[30];
    float p_price;
    float s_price;
    float profit;
}c_inven[100];
```

What I want to Do is read it and send it to other function which will store it in another structure.
here's my code I used for reading

```
fread(&c_inven,sizeof(inventory),1,cars);
```

and I am Sending it using this function call

```
sort(c_inven);
*printing[1]*
```

and this function header to receive it
    void sort(struct inventory sort_inven[100])
but when i print the values with for loop, it just prints values of c_inven[0].xxxxxx and returns me with blank space when i move to c_inven.[1].

Please Help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fread call only reads one entry. You would need to call

```
fread(&c_inven,sizeof(struct inventory),100,cars);
```

assuming that you malloced enough memory where `c_inven` points to.

Also, if you check `fread`'s return value it tells you how many entries it read.

Printing `c_inven[1]` prints whatever is there, maybe the next variable in memory.